# Optional user input of a variable from the console in C++?

Tags: c++, input, stream, option-type

I  have a program where I want to `cin>>` from the console 3 variables on one line - one string, an integer and a char. However, the third variable (char) should be optional - the user can enter the string s and the integer n, without entering a char. If the variable `symb` is not entered, then it ought to be initialized with `symb=' ';`(whitespace). I have heard that this could be achieved by using `sstream` but I could not figure out exactly how could I do this if it is even possible?

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string s;
int n;
char symb;
int main()
{
    cin>>s>>n>>symb (optional);
    if(symb is not entered)
    {
        symb = ' ';
        (whitespace)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you could treat the input as a whole string, then see how many different elements it contains: if there is nothing after the integer, it does not contain a character, if it does, put it in the variable

Comment: Read it as one line. Put in an input string stream. Read `s` and `n` from the string stream. Separately attempt to read `symb` from the string stream. Check if the attempt worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can getline and then parse it, but i think this solution is simple and easy to understand.

```
int main() {
    cin >> s >> n;
    symb = cin.get();
    if (symb == ' ') symb = cin.get(); // then we try to read our symbol
    if (symb == '\n' || symb == EOF) symb = ' ';
    cout << s << "|" << n << "|" << symb << "|\n";
    return 0;
}
```

but EOF can be == -1, and in c++ char doesn't have to be signed so i would recommend using peek to check if eof:

```
 if (cin.peek() == char_traits<char>::eof()) {/* EOF */}
 else {/* here you know the next char you get won't be EOF */}
```

or simply use int tmp_symb like that:

```
int main() {
    cin >> s >> n;
    int tmp_symb;
    tmp_symb = cin.get();
    if (tmp_symb == ' ') tmp_symb = cin.get(); // then we try to read our symbol
    if (tmp_symb == '\n' || tmp_symb == EOF) tmp_symb = ' ';
    symb = tmp_symb;
    cout << s << "|" << n << "|" << symb << "|\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but it will not be beautiful and it cannot be done in one line. The idea is: when you press *Enter* you can have more in the input buffer that you have asked for. You can access that additional input. Just ask for the non-optional data, then check if there is more data in the buffer with peek(). It will return the next character as integer or wait. In your situation, there will be at least a newline character from pressing *Enter*. Otherwise there will be a whitespace separating the next token from your integer n.

```
std::string s;
int n;
char symb;
std::cin >> s >> n;

if (std::cin.peek() == '\n') // pressed enter after string?
{
    sym = ' ';
}
else
{
    std::cin >> symb; // will not block if we have char in buffer
}
```

It starts to get ugly when you want to treat the case of only trailing whitespace after the int n. Then peek would return not newline but space or tab and `cin >> symb` would block waiting for a character. We could insert `std::noskipws` to make `cin >> symb` return. However, what we actually want is to skip spaces and tabs:

```
...
}
else
{
    std::cin.ignore();  // discard chars until eof or 1 char extracted
    std::cin >> std::noskipws >> symb; 
}
// now treat sym is whitspace
```

This is still not very robust. Better read the whole line and parse it as has heen suggested in other answers.